# Security Predicate for Community User

Tags: community, security, einstein-analytics, crm-analytics

For a community user to see relevant records in community, what should be the security predicate if account owner id and related opportunity owner is owned by the logged in user?

I understand that

> datasetName.column == "$Users.xyz__c"

should be the syntax.

I tried 'Account.OwnerId' == "$User.Id" and it shows only those account that are owner by logged in user in CRMA embedded in Community.

What should be the right approach for sharing salesforce records in community using security predicate for ACR (Account Contact Relationship) in dataset with logged in User.

Comment: Are you asking about reporting on shared records or how to share? Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour).

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I was asking for steps to share records on community using security predicate. Updated my question. Thanks for pointing it out.